# Is my loop wrong ? Do I misuse ReadFile() and I/O completion port ?

Tags: winapi, readfile, io-completion-ports

I want to implement a server/client using named pipes (for IPC).I'm using async (overlapped) connections and I/O completion port (I searched a lot and it seems that it is the most efficient way to do that).

First here are the codes:

server: http://pastebin.com/XxeXdunC

and client: http://pastebin.com/fbCH2By8

The problem is in the server (i can improve the client but i will do that when the server works).

I use I/O completion port like that : basically, I run a thread in which I call ReadFile(). If it returns TRUE, I get all the data, if it returns FALSE, and the error is ERROR_IO_PENDING, I wait with GetQueuedCompletionStatus().

What is strange is that, even if I read all the data, the last ReadFile() call fails and the error is ERROR_IO_PENDING

The thread in which I call ReadFile() is beginning line 64 of the server code.

The client sends 24 bytes (the string "salut, c'est le client !") and the ReadFile() buffer is of length 5 bytes (to check how my server deals data that is larger than the Readfile() buffer)

The output is:

```
waiting for client...
WaitForMultipleObjects : 0
client connected (1)
ReadFile 1 msg (5 -> 05) : salut
ReadFile 2 msg (5 -> 10) : salut, c'e
ReadFile 2 msg (5 -> 15) : salut, c'est le
ReadFile 2 msg (5 -> 20) : salut, c'est le clie
ReadFile 2 msg (4 -> 24) : salut, c'est le client !
ReadFile2: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 0 255 003D3A18
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 5 255 003D3A2C
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 5 255 003D3A2C
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 5 255 003D3A2C
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 5 255 003D3A2C
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
GQCIOS 4 255 003D3A2C
ReadFile3: ERROR_IO_PENDING
ReadFile1: ERROR_IO_PENDING
```

What I do not understand is that even if I read all the data, ReadFile() still returns a pending operation (it's the "ReadFile2: ERROR_IO_PENDING" error message after the last "msg" output)

Is my loop wrong ? Do I misuse ReadFile() / GetQueuedCompletionStatus() ?

thank you

Comment: The problem seems to be the mode of the pipe. I have to use the message mode (client and server), but it does not help : the first ReadFile() call fails, the number of read bytes is 0 and the error is ERROR_MORE_DATA. Although it is normal to have such error, where are the first 5 bytes stored ?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your write related function? it seems that your code is in wrong order. In the `_read_data_cb` routine, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` should be called first, then depending on the `lpOverlapped` parameter, the received data should be ready in the buffer that you specified in the ReadFile function. Since you're calling Readfile without checking whether `OVERLAPPED` is a overlapped structure for the send context or recv context, you're not getting the expected output. The following code should clear things up:

```
while(TRUE)
{
    bReturnValue=GetQueuedCompletionStatus(pIOCPServer->m_pIOCP, &dwBytesTransferred,(DWORD *)pClient,reinterpret_cast<LPOVERLAPPED*>(&pOverlapped),INFINITE);
    if(!bReturnValue)
    {
        if(NULL==pOverlapped)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
    else
    {
        if(pOverlapped==NULL)
            continue;
    }
    if(dwBytesTransferred==0)
        break;
    if(lpOverlapped==&(pClient->m_pRecvContext->overlapped))
        pClient->handleRecvEvent(dwBytesTransferred)
    else if(lpOverlapped==&(pClient->m_pSendContext->overlapped))
        pClient->handleSendEvent(dwBytesTransferred)
}
...
```